# How to move a view with the keyboard while attached similar to .toolbar

Tags: swiftui

I want to have the `TextEditor1` to be on the `bottom` of the app, then when user taps on the `TextEditor1` to type the message, the `TextEditor1` should attached to the `keyboard` and move up with it. I used the following code, it attaches to it through the `.toolbar`, but don't know how to make `TextEditor1` stay in the bottom of the app etc and then move up with the keyboard. Image is attached for further clarification.

```
import SwiftUI


struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var textTyped: String = "this is textttt"
    
    var body: some View {
        TextEditor (text: $textTyped)
            .toolbar {
                        ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard) {
                           
                            TextEditor1()
                            
                            
                        }
                     
            }
            .frame(height: 200, alignment: .leading)
            .padding(.horizontal, 10)
}
}

struct TextEditor1: View {
    
    @State var textTyped: String = "this is textttt"
    
    var body: some View {
        TextEditor (text: $textTyped)
            .frame(height: 200, alignment: .leading)
            .padding(.horizontal, 10)
                     
            }
            
}
```

[image]

Comment: This code makes no sense. You start with a `TextEditor` on screen and then add another, in a separate view, with its own `@State` variable. The original text editor already responds to the keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want? I also put a colored `.background()` on to see the outlines of the `TextEditor`. I find it helps to be able to visualize the extent of the views.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var textTyped: String = "this is textttt"
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            TextEditor (text: $textTyped)
                .frame(height: 200, alignment: .leading)
//                .padding(.horizontal, 10)
                .padding()
                .background(Color.yellow.opacity(0.2))
        }
    }
}
```